# Hybris hMC login configuration

Tags: authentication, sap-commerce-cloud

Forgive me here if this is a complete newbie question.  At work, they are (as I am as well) trying to onboard me into using Hybris.  While the documentation on the wiki.hybris site is not well placed, most of the information is there.  I am however having some trouble finding **how to change default HMC logins credential?**

When I rebuilt the server, it forced me to reinitialize the database, and thus changed all of the logins.  I managed to find the cms login, but I am curious as to **where the HMC admin login is stored at?**, as it appears to be changed, and I need to find it.  I know that it heavily leverages Spring, and I searched the `.xml` files for a password, but I am not finding what I need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

they are exist in different location in `.impex` files (importer files) , that you initialize the store for the first time , those `.impex` files got imported to your database

example of one location :

```
ext-template\yacceleratorinitialdata\resources\yacceleratorinitialdata\import\common\user-groups.impex
```

as there are multiple starter stores that comes with hybris (accelerator, telcoaccelerator, and powershop b2b) I suggest you to search as text for username or password in all files extention = .impex then change for files that belong to your store .

i did a quick search , not only in .impex file , the hmc admin/nimda seems to changes from

```
/bin/platform/project.properties


# Login and password for the automatic logging into the hMC
hmc.default.login=admin
hmc.default.password=nimda
```

hope that helped you .

Thanks

Comment: I knew about the .impex files, completely forgot about the project.properties file.  Thank you!  I'm hoping that there is no other place where they over-rode the values.  The values ARE:hmc.default.login=admin
hmc.default.password=nimda  so I am not seeing it being overridden.

Answer (score 2):

When searching for Out Of The Box impex files, search against "*.impex" & "*.csv" as many of the impex scripts are written as csv as well. In rare case, you may also find *.txt also catering to impex scripts.

You will not be able to find an impex file where "admin" user credentials are maintained. It is "nimda" by default and may be changed via impex file or simply by HMC under users.

```
/bin/platform/project.properties
```

Any property file will have no impact on the user credentials, the mentioned property file just defaults the jsp page with filled in values in the login form. This has nothing to do with the current/changed credentials.